# Deep Linking on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hello to all community !

Any news about changes on "Deeplinking" on Illustrator ? Mine is still not assuming in an automatic manner.
a) You have to open the .ai file that contain the PSD link to update that psd and save that .ai file
b) only then the linked .ai will update the changes in the other .ai file.

Any update on that ?

Ideally I would like to have a folder to contain the linked psd's and also final products that combine vector and those psd's. That way I would have to update changes only on those arts of that folder to be assumed on all plans for production...

Regards !

Answer (score 4):

I've just updated my Adobe CC applications and have tested this for you. If you have Adobe CC, you can quickly confirm this yourself.

### Currently installed

- Photoshop v 21.2.3
- Illustrator v 24.3
- InDesign v 15.1.2

### Illustrator

Illustrator *doesn't* support the kind of deep linking you want.

- Place `image.psd` in `documentA.ai`.
- Close `documentA.ai`.
- Place `documentA.ai` in `documentB.ai`.
- Close `documentB.ai`.
- Change `image.psd` and save it.

If I open `documentB.ai` there is no warning whatsoever that `documentA.ai` has changed.

[image]

If I open `documentA.ai` the image *automatically* updates, but the document doesn't get a `*` after the filename and can't be saved until I make some sort of change and undo it. Seems like a bug.

### InDesign

InDesign *partly* supports deep linking.

- Place `image.psd` in `documentA.indd`.
- Close `documentA.indd`.
- Place `documentA.indd` in `documentB.indd`.
- Close `documentB.indd`.
- Change `image.psd` and save it.

If I open `documentB.indd` there is a warning that `documentA.indd` has changed and the menu item can be unfolded to see exactly which placed file has changed.

[image]

It isn't possible to update the link (which is indicated by that warning sign with feet) without opening `documentA.indd` and saving it though (which is why is say that deeplinking is only partly supported).

If I open `documentA.indd` it isn't automatically updated, but I'm prompted that a placed file has changed. Unlike in Illustrator, if I choose to update the changed image the document has changed and can be saved.

Comment: I'm going to be THAT smart mouth. ;) what about if you link INDD to an AI that's linked to a PSD?

Comment: @Alith7 That's not enough, we must go deeper!

Comment: @Alith7, your will rip a hole in the spacetime continuum. 

Comment: LOL, TBH, I didn't even know you COULD link an INDD to another INDD file.... WHY?!?! Why woulld you do such insanity?!?!

Comment: Thank You so much  Wolff. That's right, as I expected. That's a shame it's not updated yet. Many times you have to create a product of both content image and vector and create a file to be linked on some pre-press layouts. I do this to preserve the safety of knowing that there is no other file being used instead and therefore having a single folder for all links on that job. What I'm doing is changing the paradigm and never do a change directly on the psd file, but yes, edit the composed ai file and only on that one edit the psd. This way it updates...

Comment: @LuisMonteiro, you are welcome! Please *accept* the answer so people can see that this answer has an accepted answer.